# when using malloc to change size of memory of structure

Tags: c

```
struct node *add_to_list (struct node *list, int n)
{
    struct node *new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
}
```

in this code new_node is defined in 'struct node' structure so new_node has memory size of struct node

but in fourth line new_node's size of memory is redefined

but when malloc(sizeof(struct node)) is executed, i think there is  no change in size of new node because new node is already has memory size same with 'struct node' memory size

so why this code is in 4'th line

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're allocating memory for a `struct node`. The amount of memory has to be the size of that structure.

Comment: This should be explained clearly in any tutorial on pointers and `malloc`.

Comment: "there is no change in size of `new node`" --> Correct. `new node` is a pointer.  Its soze foes not change.  In `new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, memory is allocated and the beginning of that allocation is assigned to `new node`.

Comment: *"new_node is defined in 'struct node' structure "* - I believe that should read, "new_node is defined as a pointer to a 'struct node' structure". Get the vernacular right or you'll just prolong the agony. It will also help you better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This defines a pointer:

```
struct node *new_node;
```

The size of the pointer is 32 bit or 64 bit depending of the architecture.

```
new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

This actually allocates the memory for `node` of the size of that structure.

BTW, it's widely recommended to check if the result of `malloc()` invocation is `NULL` or you may run into very nasty problems later.

Just in case you're wondering, this, for example, creates `node` (not a pointer):

```
struct node new_node;
```

Notice the missing star `*` symbol.

Comment: The size of a pointer could also be 16 bit, actually any number depending on the target system. ;-)